# Scroll QTextBrowser to the top

Tags: qt, qt4, scrollbar, qtextedit, browser-scrollbars

I have the following:

```
QString html = ui->DetailsTextBrowser->document()->toHtml();
html = details.replace("#VERSION", "1.0");
ui->DetailsTextBrowser->document()->setHtml(details);
```

Unfortunately after the HTML content of the DetailsTextBrowser is set the document is scrolled to the bottom.

I tried without success:

```
ui->DetailsTextBrowser->verticalScrollBar()->setValue(0);
```

Is there a way to scroll QTextBrowser to the top?

Comment: im curious to know why the other methods do not work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
QTextCursor cursor = ui->DetailsTextBrowser->textCursor();
cursor.setPosition(0);
ui->DetailsTextBrowser->setTextCursor(cursor);
```